How to check if data from API is empty in map in astrojs
I am retrieving data from wordpress rest api. I build a frontend in astrojs. Sometimes, it can happen that e.g. for an article it is not neccessary to upload images into a gallery. But the frontend is crashing in this case, because the funtion .map cannot handle an empty response. How can I check, if a response is empty and then map only if it is not empty? I tried an if-statement checking if galleryImages.size != 0 - But I cannot write an if-statement in astrojs in the html section.
here I map the Images from the gallery api:
var galleryImages = await Promise.all(
gallery.map(async (image: any) => {
  const imageRes = await fetch(`https://${BASE_URL}/media/` + image);
  const imagePath = await imageRes.json();
  return imagePath.source_url;
}),

);
here I map the galleryImages to show in the frontend:
        <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-10 mt-12">
      {
        galleryImages?.map((image: any) => {
          return (
            <div class="w-64" data-lightbox="true">
              <img src={image} alt={title} class="w-auto h-auto" width=1920 height=1080 />
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>

What I try to do:
    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-10 mt-12">
          { if (galleryImages.size != 0) {
            galleryImages?.map((image: any) => {
              return (
                <div class="w-64" data-lightbox="true">
                  <img src={image} alt={title} class="w-auto h-auto" width=1920 height=1080 />
                </div>
              );
            })}
else {
<div><p>Nothing to show here </p></div>
}
          }
        </div>


use filter on the array to remove empty values : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
